# Reset live tile to default

Tags: windows-8, live-tile

Should be straightforward still I can't find it. How can I remove all my live tile updates and revert back to the default tile from code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [TileUpdater.Clear](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.tileupdater.clear.aspx).

> Removes all updates and reverts the tile to its default content as declared in the app's manifest.

Comment: Ouch... I had a class with the same name and it hides the Windows.UI.Notifications.TileUplader. Thanks.